# Two form submit on same page, only the first one works. JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two form submits on a page both doing the same thing.

One is on a toolbar/navbar and the other in the main page.
 
The problem I have is that once I added the form on the toolbar the one on the main page never has the search value when it fires, if I comment out the one in the toolbar then the main page has the value.

```
//Toolbar submit
<form>
  <div class="input-append">
    <input type="text" class="span3" placeholder="Enter name" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn-u">Go</button>
   </div>
 </form>

// Main page submit
<form class="form-inline margin-bottom-5">
  <div class="input-append">
    <input type="text" class="input-xxlarge" placeholder="Enter class name">
    <button type="submit" class="btn-u">Go</button>
  </div>
</form>

//JavaScript/JQuery
$("form").submit(function (e) {

  var searchTerm = $("input:first").val();
  if (searchTerm === '') {
    // This part of the code is reached for the second submit,
    // I have tried using id on the submit but have the same result
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the below, at the moment it's looking for the first input on the page, this will look for the first input within the form that's actually been submitted.

```
var searchTerm = $("input:first").val();
```

To

```
var searchTerm = $(this).find("input:first").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `var searchTerm = $("input:first").val();` nothing tells that you are looking for the first input in the submitted form. Here you are looking for the first input of the first form of the page. replace it by `var searchTerm = $(this).find("input:first").val();`

Edit: ho, I'm too slow to answer... mwell, at least it confirms the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use a 'this' to make sure you're looking for the first input in the form you're submitting:

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {

   var searchTerm = $(this).find("input:first").val();
   if (searchTerm === '') {
      // This part of the code is reached for the second submit,
      // I have tried using id on the submit but have the same result
   }
```